# Calculate yearly growth rate of column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
       person code  year            Height                Size ...
0   73163529000108  2013      6.293900e+07        6.292900e+07
1   73163529000108  2012      5.206400e+07        5.282500e+07
2   73163529000108  2014      7.293900e+07        5.292900e+07
3   68402163000134  2013      3.225900e+07        2.389000e+06
4   68402163000134  2012      5.779300e+07        5.304800e+07
...
```

I want to include a "Height Year Growth" and "Size Year Growth" columns, so it gets to look something like this:

```
       person code  year        Height  Height Y Growth          Size ...
0   73163529000108  2013  6.293900e+07           0.2096  6.292900e+07
1   73163529000108  2012  5.206400e+07                   5.282500e+07
2   73163529000108  2014  7.293900e+07           0,1589  5.292900e+07
3   68402163000134  2013  3.225900e+07                   2.389000e+06
4   68402163000134  2012  5.779300e+07          -0.4419  5.304800e+07  
...
```

I don't mind the format it comes out, I just need it to be scalable. I'm having a hard time getting to it. Can someone suggest an alternative?

Comment: What is Height Y Growth ?  How should it be calculated ?

Comment: can you post the df code, please? and also what is the year growth representing? the height difference between years of same person by person code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are looking for `pct_change`

```
df[['YC','SC']]=df.sort_values(['year']).groupby('personcode')[['Height','Size']].pct_change()
df
Out[1083]: 
       personcode  year  Height    Size        YC        SC
0  73163529000108  2013  6.2939  6.2929  0.208878  0.191273
1  73163529000108  2012  5.2064  5.2825       NaN       NaN
2  73163529000108  2014  7.2939  5.2929  0.158884 -0.158909
3  68402163000134  2013  3.2259  2.3890 -0.441818 -0.549653
4  68402163000134  2012  5.7793  5.3048       NaN       NaN
```

Comment: One issue. It might not be a problem, but if a year is missing for some reason (bad data?) you will still get yearly change values.